# (Select all that apply) survey answers in R dataframe

Tags: r

I'm using Windows7 with Rstudio. I have a data frame that has a few columns that contain a factor mixture of 4 answers or NAs (4 answers, select all that apply or select none). I'm having one hell of a time separating the levels so that I can tell how many respondents selected.

```
data<- c("cats", "dogs", "cats, dogs", "cats, dogs, birds(with, commas, randomly)")
data<-data.frame(as.factor(data))
df<-as.data.frame(cbind((1:100),data))
df[,1]<-NULL
df
```

How do I show that the user selected dogs (one level) and cats (another level), rather than selecting dog AND cats (as a single level, separate form dogs and/or cats)?

That is to say, how do I show:
dogs is 1
cats is 2
dogs and cats is 1,2
dogs and cats and birds is 1,2,3 without running into issues with commas, of course, and possibly in some other manner if necessary

I've searched Google up and down, and I'm just not getting it. I can't use the mChoice function (Hmisc package) correctly and I'm having all sorts of issues. I was hoping I could find a solution in this course, specifically, but I believe to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you really need 100 row of sample data? Also please show desired output with given input.

Comment: So what is the desired result?  You have `(with, commas, randomly)` inside the last string.  Is that kept or removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('\\w+', list('dogs'=1, 'cats'=2, 'birds'=3), data)
#[1] "2"       "1"       "2, 1"    "2, 1, 3"
```

NOTE:  I assume the `(with, commas, randomly)` part is just like saying `etc...`.  Even if, it is already present in the data, the `gsubfn` solution will return the output.

---

Or another option would to split the string and then convert to `factor` and coerce to `numeric`

```
sapply(strsplit(data, ',\\s*'), function(x)
    toString(as.numeric(factor(x, levels=c('dogs', 'cats', 'birds')))))
#[1] "2"       "1"       "2, 1"    "2, 1, 3"
```

#### data

```
data <- c("cats", "dogs", "cats, dogs", "cats, dogs, birds")
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need to do with the actual data frame. How do I transform three possible responses to read 1, 2, and 3 (or NA if there are no responses) so that I can uses those responses when analyzing the relationship between that column and, say, a gender column? In essence, what you've shown above shows me what type of outcome I want to see in the dataframe, but how to I transform the dataframe to show these types of answers? I want to be able to show in a graph that so many users chose choice 1 and so many, choice 2, but not have those who chose 1 and 2 be separate altogether

Comment: @jnowat I am not entirely sure what you wanted.  If you want to split up the string.  `v1 <- gsubfn('\\w+', list('dogs'=1, 'cats'=2, 'birds'=3), data); lapply(strsplit(v1, ', '), as.numeric)` should give you the expected output.

Comment: `> sapply(strsplit(new$gender, ',\\s*'), function(x)
+ toString(as.numeric(factor(x, levels=c('Male','Female')))))
Error in strsplit(new$gender, ",\\s*") : non-character argument` I keep getting the message that the items in my dataframe columns aren't characters, so how do I apply this to factors (i.e., new$gender is "Male", "Female", or "NA")? After learning this, I can accept this answer and pursue another question regarding splitting the 1,2,3,etc. apart in analyses. Thanks for helping me, here

Comment: @jnowat It seems that the `gender` column is `factor` You can use `strsplit(as.character(new$ecup2$gender), ....`